# Why did the crust get too hard on my Blueberry Cheesecake?

Tags: baking, crust, cheesecake, crumb-crust

I recently made a no bake blueberry cheesecake with its crust made of cookie crumbs(Used Digestive Biscuits as cookies), Brown sugar and melted butter. After keeping the cake overnight in the refrigerator, the crust turned out to be too solid, so solid that not it was difficult to cut it using a knife. What did go wrong? Did i keep it in the refrigerator for too long? Or should i increase the cookie crumbs or the melted butter content to avoid it?

Comment: What was your ratio of cookie to butter? And can you give more details as to the process of preparing the crust? (cook, temp, time, etc..

Comment: @talon8 I read "no bake"...

Comment: @Stephie : yes, on the crust side of things,  the digestive biscuits might've been roughly crumbled, turned to dust in a food processor, or somewhere in between.  I seem to recall cutting the crust of cheesecakes is always a bit of a problem.

Comment: Proportions are necessary, but one option is to just omit the crust and use the biscuits as a garnish.

Comment: @Stephie, the reason I ask about the crust, is often the crust is baked even when the "no-bake" cheesecake itself is not. I do a similar recipe with graham crackers, partially crushed, and butter (I partially bake it). It turns out perfectly. I would expect digestive biscuits to be not that different.

Comment: @talon8 The origin recipe made use of grahan Cracker crumbs and melted butter, but i stay in india and i could not get my hands on graham cracker crumbs.. So replaced them with Digestive Biscuits..

Comment: So how much butter are you using compared to your biscuits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ratio of butter to cookie is probably the main problem here: using too much butter and refrigerating it overnight will give your crust the texture of... well... *refrigerated butter*.

So, change the recipe and use **one** of the following options:

1. Lightly soak the cookies in coffee/tea/lemonade/Cognac/whatever liquid is to your taste.
2. Use less volume of butter and add the same volume of cookies.
3. Powder the cookies in a blender
4. Use a mixture of oil and butter (take one with a neutral taste like grape-seed oil).  Test out a few spoonfuls in some shot glasses (50/50, 60/40, ... until you get the texture you want)

You can also combine the above, but that would be riskier: change one parameter at a time...

<sub>Can I have a piece of that perfect blueberry cheesecake now? **:-)**</sub>

Comment: Sure you can have it.. I'll try it out.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It’s often simply a case of compressing the mix too much! I have done this many times before - I press the cookie and butter mix down into the tin too hard. This can make it very hard to cut through once it’s set. Try compressing it more gently: it doesn’t need to be packed in to set well as a base.