# Graham Crust Cheesecake is so hard to cut?

Tags: crust, cheesecake

How come with I follow the instructions to the letter on the Nasbisco Graham box for the cheesecake recipe that my crust come out so hard to cut upon serving? I dont think I'm over cooking it and I alway chill it in the refrigerator overnite! Please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did the crust get too hard on my Blueberry Cheesecake?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/63490/why-did-the-crust-get-too-hard-on-my-blueberry-cheesecake)

Comment: For those of us who don't have access to see the recipe, can you summarize it here?

Comment: @Joe the blueberry cheesecake question was about a no-bake recipe, so I don't think this would be a duplicate.

Comment: @DebbieM. it very well might be. I don't have a box of nabisco graham crackers to check on the recipe, but some googling leads me to believe that the recipe on the box is at least a no-bake crust recipe depending on chilled butter to keep the crust together.

Comment: It *could* be a duplicate, but we don't exactly know, so I think I'm fine leaving it as a related question in comments.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that you are simply pressing too hard and compressing the crust too much. Use the bottom of a glass or measuring cup to press just hard enough to keep the crust in place. Very little pressure is necessary.

Comment: Agreed with Jolenealaska... If unbaked, the hardening of butter alone won't make it so very hard... The density is the culprit...